# Adding event handler on radio group in Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I want to add a event where if I click on Single IP radio button one IP address field should come in the form and if I click on the IP range radio button then two IP address field should come i.e. "from: " and "to: ". I have used the item id for the IP fields. but it is not working for me. "modifiedIpRange" i have defined in controller file.

```
{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'Type',
            name: 'type',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Single IP',
                inputValue: 'SINGLE',
                checked: true,
            },{
                boxLabel: 'IP Range',
                inputValue: 'RANGE'
            }] 
 listeners: {
     change: 'modifiedIpRange'
 }
```

}

```
modifiedIpRange: function(item, newVal, oldVal) {
switch (newVal.type){
    case 'SINGLE': Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ipField')[0].setHidden(false) && Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#startIpField')[0].setHidden(true) && Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#endIpField')[0].setHidden(true);
    break;
    case 'RANGE': Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#startIpField')[0].setHidden(false) && Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#endIpField')[0].setHidden(false) && Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ipField')[0].setHidden(true);
    break;
}
  
},
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When "Single IP" radio is enable then only one textfield should come in the form otherwise for "IP Range" two textfield should come in the form

Comment: What ExtJS version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
var rgChange = function(item, newVal, oldVal) {
    switch (newVal.type){
        case '1': Ext.get('txt2').hide();
        break;
        case '2': Ext.get('txt2').show();
        break;
    }
  
};


Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'RadioGroup Example',
    width: 500,
    height: 325,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'Type',
            name: 'type',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Single IP',
                inputValue: '1',
                checked: true,
            },{
                boxLabel: 'IP Range',
                inputValue: '2'
            }],
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    fn: rgChange
                }
            },
        },
         {
            xtype:'textfield',
            id: 'txt1',
            fieldLabel:'From'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            id: 'txt2',
            fieldLabel: 'to',
            hidden:true
        },
        
    ]
});
```